# Static vs. public C#

Tags: c#, static, instantiation

I know that it's been answered multiple times here on SO, but I still don't get the nuts of bolts of what exactly it means to instantiate a class.  I read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15269/Static-Keyword-Demystified) and it did help my understanding.

I know that static classes like `Console` cannot be used with the `new` expression like `Console c = new Console()` because there aren't any instance variables in that class.  I also know that static classes provide on 'generic' methods and are generally used for `Math` functions.  I know that once you instantiate a class like `Double d = new Double();` you are now given access to whatever methods are inside of the `Double` class.

I know these facts but I feel like I don't really understand what they actually MEAN.  Could someone give an example of where a static class is absolutely necessary and one where creating an instance of a class is absolutely necessary?

Comment: Look at the `Console` or `Math` classes vs. the `Exception` or `Button` classes.

Comment: If you have only one 'Console' you can make it static. If you have multiple 'Double's, you can't make them static.

Comment: ^ make these answers... there are things to discuss in there.

Comment: the **only** time a static class is "absolutely necessary" is for creating extension methods.  Every other time there is no need to make a *class* static, only methods or fields; making the class static only prevents people from writing pointless (but not harmful) code.  Just focus on learning when you should have a static vs instance method/property/field.  If you happen to have all static members in a class you can (optionally) make that class static (just because...).

Comment: As far as your title goes, *static* and *public* are two completely different concepts. You can have a non-static public class, a static non-public class, and so on.

Comment: making a class static prevents the meaningless code Console c = new Console(), correct?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Yes, but that code is not harmful, just pointless.  What reason do you have to prevent someone from doing that?  The code would be no different than `object obj = new object()`.  Neither can do anything useful (other than be used to lock on) but neither is causing any real harm.  It might make the purpose of the class a bit clearer to other coders, but even without making the class static they'll figure it out quickly enough.  Also note that you can make the class sealed and add a private default constructor to prevent anyone from newing one up (without using `static`).

Comment: @TimRogers duly noted.  I think comments like this are helpful to whomever might read this question after this discussion is done and good possibly be confused.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Think of a class like a set of blueprints. Instantiating a class is like taking the blueprints and building the item. When an engineer designs a car, he comes up with the design. That would be the class. After the car is designed, the plans are handed off to the assembly line to be built. Each car that rolls off the line would be an instance of that design.

When the car is still just a design, you can't really do anything with it. You can't open its door if there's no car. Once you have the instance of a car, you can manipulate it. You can open the door, start the engine, etc. The same goes for a class like `Double`. Once you have the instance, you can manipulate it.

A static class, like `Console`, are classes that don't have instances. They're more like a way to group useful related functionality. In the case of `Console`, the functionality is used to interact with the command line. `Math` is used to group mathematics related code. `Configuration` is used to read/manipulate configuration files. None of these things require you to create anything unique for them to work.

Comment: It is a very simple yet powerful explanation of `class` and `object`.

Comment: this is a good analogy. so say if we had a class `Person` with attributes `sex, weight, height` we'd have to instantiate (create) a Person.  However if a method existed `BrushYourHair` that would be a static method because people by default would have hair (excluding bald people, of course), and you don't have to create a person to peform that action.  Is that a good analogy?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - It's close. But you'd still need to know which person was brushing their hair which you could pass as a parameter to the static method. It might look something like `Hygiene.BrushHair(instanceOfSomePerson);`

Comment: @wootscootinboogie No.  `BrushYourHair` is something that a specific person does.  One person can brush their hair without all people brushing their hair.

Comment: @JustinNiessner That wouldn't be a very good design chioce; it's more c style coding.  It would be better for `BrushHair` to be an instance method of `Person`

Comment: what would be a good example of a static method inside the `Person` class then?

Comment: @Servy - It depends on what the `Person` class was responsible for. Maybe in your design it shouldn't be responsible for hygiene, in which case having a static utility class that handled the common methods would be useful.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie I probably wouldn't put a static method (at least not public ones) inside of `Person`.  Maybe something like a static int `WorldPopulation` or something like that, but realistically I would probably want that in another class.  I suggest you just spend some time looking through the language classes.  See what types of classes they make static or non-static.  There are thousands upon thousands of examples right in there.  (Try to focus on newer ones; some of the older ones have outdated designs just there for backwards compatibility.)

Comment: You have certainly helped to clarify this for me.  I've been reading about C# for about two weeks now and making my second pass through a beginner's book to avoid just memorizing syntax and actually learning.  This was helpful, thanks to servy, @justin, et. al

Answer (score 2):

A public class must be called in application by another class, for exampel this may be a class of data access (called by businnes layer).

A static class need not necessarily the creation of an instance for example tracing or logging class.

Answer (score 1):

One (perhaps over) simplified example for thinking about static is the following:

If you have the class Dog; you could instantiate the class to create Dog Poodle = new Dog(); and Dog Labrador = new Dog(); 
If the Dog class has a variable hairColor, then for Poodle and Labrador, hairColor could be different. The two different instances are seperate.

If however, you added a static variable to Dog called numberOfDogs, and incremented the variable every time a new Dog was instantiated (you could do this is the constructor for example), then the variable would count the total number of Dogs, and would be the same number regardless of which instance of Dog you checked.
This is useful (and dangerous) depending on how you use it.